# Send data to CSS Modal Popup

Tags: html, css

I need to manipulate my Mysql data on:

1. I populate Mysql DB content on HTML table and every row have "EDIT" and "DELETE" buttons...(HTML "a" tags buttons)
2. When I click on "Edit" button a pure CSS3 Modal Popup is open, where I need to Edit a record on the row,
3. If I click on "Delete" button a pure CSS3 Modal Popup is open for delete record confirmation if the answer is "YES" proceed to delete the Record if the answer is "NO" should back to the parent page...

Populate a list of selected records is working. CSS3 Modal Popup is working...
The question is how can I send arguments to the Modal Popup to manipulate the data?

Could someone help with this.

Thanks.

Comment: There are hundreds of ways to do it.  Question is, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The ways I would do this in no particular order:

1. Separate modals for every item on the table.  Could be cumbersome, and is definitely not efficient, but would get the job done without using Javascript.
2. Javascript - Have a `data-id` and `data-table` attribute in the button.  When clicked, populate the modal with Javascript via AJAX.
3. Javascript - Store table data in JSON array.  Use above attributes to access specific elements of the JSON table object.
4. Javascript - Store the JSON object directly in the `data` attribute if possible and load up the modal when clicked.
5. Have a hidden `<div>` with all the content, and when the button is clicked, transfer the HTML to the modal.

Really there are many other ways to get it done.  Pick one that looks easy, efficient, and safe, and give it a go.  Post back here when you get stuck and we will be glad to help you.